# UIImage on CGLayer

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ipod

I want to draw a simple UIImage on CGLayer, but I cannot find any useful resources to do it. Kindly tell me how to draw UIImage on CGLayer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it this you are looking for ?

```
CGContextRef layerCtx = CGLayerGetContext(layer);
 CGContextDrawImage(layerCtx, (CGRect){ CGPointZero, myImage.size }, myImage.CGImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the Graphic context from the CGLayer, using the CGLayerGetContext function.
After that, just push the new context into the stack, and draw the image inside the graphic context.